# Plotting family of functions with qplot without duplicating data

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Given family of functions *f(x;q)* (*x* is argument and *q* is parameter) I'd like to visulaize this function family on *x* taking from the interval *[0,1]* for 9 values of *q* (from 0.1 to 0.9). So far my solution is:

```
f = function(p,q=0.9) {1-(1-(p*q)^3)^1024}
x = seq(0.0,0.99,by=0.01)
q = seq(0.1,0.9,by=0.1)

qplot(rep(x,9), f(rep(x,9),rep(q,each=100)), colour=factor(rep(q,each=100)), 
      geom="line", size=I(0.9), xlab="x", ylab=expression("y=f(x)"))
```

I get quick and easy visual with *qplot*:

[image]

My concern is that this method is rather memory hungry as I need to duplicate x for each parameter and duplicate each parameter value for whole x range. What would be alternative way to produce same graph without these duplications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point **ggplot** will need to have the data available to plot it and the way that package works prohibits simply doing what you want. I suppose you could set up a blank plot if you know the x and y axis limits, and then loop over the 9 values of `q`, generating the data for that `q`, and adding a `geom_line` layer to the existing plot object. However, you'll have to produce the colours for each layer yourself.

If this is representative of the size of problem you have, I wouldn't worry too much about the memory footprint. We're only talking about a two vectors of length 900

```
> object.size(rnorm(900))
7240 bytes
```

and the 100 values over the range of `x` appears sufficient to give a smooth plot.

### `for` loop to add layers to **ggplot**

```
require("ggplot2")

## something to replicate ggplot's colour palette, sure there is something
## to do this already in **ggplot** now...
ggHueColours <- function(n, h = c(0, 360) + 15, l = 65, c = 100,
                         direction = 1, h.start = 0) {
    turn <- function(x, h.start, direction) {
        (x + h.start) %% 360 * direction
    }

    if ((diff(h) %% 360) < 1) {
      h[2] <- h[2] - 360 / n
    }

    hcl(h = turn(seq(h[1], h[2], length = n), h.start = h.start,
        direction = direction), c = c, l =  l)
}

f = function(p,q=0.9) {1-(1-(p*q)^3)^1024}
x = seq(0.0,0.99,by=0.01)
q = seq(0.1,0.9,by=0.1)
cols <- ggHueColours(n = length(q))

for(i in seq_along(q)) {
  df <- data.frame(y = f(x, q[i]), x = x)
  if(i == 1) {
    plt <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line(colour = cols[i])
  } else {
    plt <- plt + geom_line(data = df, colour = cols[i])
  }
}

plt
```

which gives:

[image]

I'll leave the rest to you - I'm not familiar enough with **ggplot** to draw a legend manually.

Comment: The loop solution is the altlernative I am looking for, thanks!

Comment: @topchef Really? What sized objects are you plotting? The loop solution is just nasty - why would you want to replicate the sugar Hadley has put into **ggplot** by forcing extra layers and controlling colour by hand? I don't know but you will also have to generate the legend yourself as well.

Comment: Could you add simple loop solution with ggplot? (no need to replicate plot in details)

Comment: I can add a simple example - if it doesn't produce the legend etc, then you'll have to work that out yourself or hope someone else chimes in, or ask a follow-up question (as a separate one) on that speficic detail.

Comment: I understand. I don't find loop solution nasty before I see it. My function example is extremely simplified. I find it rather nasty to replicate data also. I was looking into loop solution and couldn't make it as I have very limited experience with ggplot. But ggplot supports layers and they conform to loop approach nicely.

Comment: @topchef OK,`for` loop example added